# SQL - Group by certain field and concat another

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, grouping, concatenation

I have a query that return the following table:

```
   P_id   S_id   Time
1  "20"     A    15 
2  "30"     B    50
3  "50"     A    99 
4  "70"     A    60
```

I want to group the table, based on the column "Sid", and sorted by Column "Time" so it will look like this:

```
        P_id       S_id   
1  "20","70","50"    A     
2       "30"         B
```

What is the best way to do this by changing the SQL query?

When trying just to add "GROUP BY S_id" I get the error:

```
SELECT list expression references column query which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:16]
```

(Meaning it doesn't know how to group the values of P_id (all strings)

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff great thanks! (Actually STRING_AGG replaces it). And how can I sort by the column Time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select s_id, group_concat(p_id order by time) as p_ids
from t
group by s_id;
```

If you want a first column that has numbers, you can add that in:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum, s_id, group_concat(p_id order by time) as p_ids
from t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
group by s_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select group_concat(P_id,',') from tablename group by S_id ;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: @RobertColumbia people just want to give reasons i dont know why.  The code will work. Why didnt you commented on Gordon Linoff's answer he also has only code in it!!!!!!!!!!!!!! not reasons rather excuses for not liking others answers!!!